# How to use a case statement in python

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a part of the code which checks for zero and gives pass or fail

```
l=[dbname,tbname,python,fact, game_table]
f_query  = "select case when count(*)=1 then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end result"
f_query += " from  qa."+row.DB_NAME
f_query += " where "+ row.Field_NAME + "=0"
```

How can I include another when statement within this code where I need to get from a list or tuple which has l=[dbname,tbname,python,fact, game_table] which are in row.DB_NAME but when they are present then the result should be 'exp'.
So, I tried something like this :

```
l=[dbname,tbname,python,fact, game_table]
f_query  = "select case when count(*)=1 then 'Pass' when row.DB_Name in l then 'exp'
            else 'Fail' end result"
f_query += " from  qa."+row.DB_NAME
f_query += " where "+ row.Field_NAME + "=0"
```

But this din't work. Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can join the list into a string and use a table alias to stitch together your SQL:

```
l=[dbname,tbname,python,fact, game_table]
f_query  = "select case when count(*)=1 then 'Pass'"
f_query += " when t1 in ({}) then 'exp'".format(','.join(l))
f_query += " else 'Fail' end result"
f_query += " from qa."+row.DB_NAME+" as t1"
f_query += " where "+ row.Field_NAME + "=0"
```

Comment: When I tried this its throwing an error, I have given the dbnames in list insdie single quotes like this l=['dbname','tbname','python,fact', 'game_table']. The error is snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 51 unexpected 'dbname'.
syntax error line 1 at position 281 unexpected 'then'.

Comment: Just updated to add parantheses. Probably a good idea to `print(f_query)` and see how it looks and make sure it runs and then adjust code as necessary.

Comment: That's coming from here: `when t1 in`. `t1` is the alias for whatever table is being queried in the `FROM` clause, but it will need the column as well. What column is are we checking with this logic? Better yet, write out the SQL by hand and execute on your database. If it's error free, then figure out how to write it dynamically. I feel like you are working backwards and it's going to be a death from a thousand edge cases.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is : `f_query += " when " + row.DB_NAME + " in ({}) then 'exp'".format(','.join(l))` I can only guess here. I have no idea what your SQL needs to look like as I can't see your data or your table layout or your schemas or your databases. I'm blind on this one.